# How to compute huge numbers with python?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently trying to find the value of x,

```
x = (math.log(X) - math.log(math.fabs(p))/math.log(g))
```

with :

```
X = 53710695204323513509337733909021562547350740845028323195225592059762435955297110591848019878050853425581981564064692996024279718640577281681757923541806197728862534268310235863990001242041406600195234734872865710114622767319497082014412908147635982838670976889326329911714511434374891326542317244606912177994106645736126820796903212224

p = 79293686916250308867562846577205340336400039290615139607865873515636529820700152685808430350565795397930362488139681935988728405965018046160143856932183271822052154707966219579166490625165957544852172686883789422725879425460374250873493847078682057057098206096021890926255094441718327491846721928463078710174998090939469826268390010887

g = 73114111352295288774462814798129374078459933691513097211327217058892903294045760490674069858786617415857709128629468431860886481058309114786300536376329001946020422132220459480052973446624920516819751293995944131953830388015948998083956038870701901293308432733590605162069671909743966331031815478333541613484527212362582446507824584241
```

Unfortunately python can't handle natively such big numbers.

How to solve this?

---

EDIT

Since a lot you wonder what i'm trying to do:

To be able to communicate in a secured fashion Alice and Bob proceed to a Diffie-Hellman key exchange. To that end they use the prime number p :

```
p = 79293686916250308867562846577205340336400039290615139607865873515636529820700152685808430350565795397930362488139681935988728405965018046160143856932183271822052154707966219579166490625165957544852172686883789422725879425460374250873493847078682057057098206096021890926255094441718327491846721928463078710174998090939469826268390010887
```

And the integer g:

```
g = 73114111352295288774462814798129374078459933691513097211327217058892903294045760490674069858786617415857709128629468431860886481058309114786300536376329001946020422132220459480052973446624920516819751293995944131953830388015948998083956038870701901293308432733590605162069671909743966331031815478333541613484527212362582446507824584241
```

Alice chooses the secret number x, she calculates X=g^x mod p and sends X through an unsecured channel to Bob.
Bob chooses the secret number y, he calculates Y=g^y mod p and sends Y through the same unsecured channel to Alice.
Both can calculate the value Z = X^y = Y^x = g^xy mod p

By spying on the channel, Charlie retrieves the value of X and Y:

```
X = 53710695204323513509337733909021562547350740845028323195225592059762435955297110591848019878050853425581981564064692996024279718640577281681757923541806197728862534268310235863990001242041406600195234734872865710114622767319497082014412908147635982838670976889326329911714511434374891326542317244606912177994106645736126820796903212224

Y = 17548462742338155551984429588008385864428920973169847389730563268852776421819130212521059041463390276608317951678117988955994615505741640680466539914477079796678963391138192241654905635203691784507184457129586853997459084075350611422541722123509121359133932497700621300814065254996649070135358792927275914472632707420292830992294921992
```

The key of this exercice is the md5sum of the value of Z

Comment: Use Numpy instead of Python to do the math.

Comment: Are the result and the intermediate values integers? Presumably not, but your inputs (in particular `p`) *are* and you apply `fabs` to one of them...

Comment: what's the expected answer?

Comment: NumPy won't handle this any better than vanilla Python. In fact, it'll break down sooner due to different long->float conversion handling.

Comment: If they're integers, python *does* handle such big numbers. arbitrary large in fact. If you need floating points, you should try the `Decimal` module, or `mpmath`

Comment: Please name your Python version and give a runnable code snippet that reproduces the error(s) you see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with the Decimal library:

```
from decimal import Decimal

X = 53710695204323513509337733909021562547350740845028323195225592059762435955297110591848019878050853425581981564064692996024279718640577281681757923541806197728862534268310235863990001242041406600195234734872865710114622767319497082014412908147635982838670976889326329911714511434374891326542317244606912177994106645736126820796903212224
p = 79293686916250308867562846577205340336400039290615139607865873515636529820700152685808430350565795397930362488139681935988728405965018046160143856932183271822052154707966219579166490625165957544852172686883789422725879425460374250873493847078682057057098206096021890926255094441718327491846721928463078710174998090939469826268390010887
g = 73114111352295288774462814798129374078459933691513097211327217058892903294045760490674069858786617415857709128629468431860886481058309114786300536376329001946020422132220459480052973446624920516819751293995944131953830388015948998083956038870701901293308432733590605162069671909743966331031815478333541613484527212362582446507824584241
X=Decimal(X)
p=Decimal(p)
g=Decimal(g)

print X.ln() - abs(p).ln()/g.ln()
```

gives

```
769.7443428855116199351294830
```

Comment: Vanilla python gives me the exact same result.

Comment: Vanilla python gives same result, and is about 900x faster than the decimal version. In python 2.7

Comment: @LucasB: What does "vanilla" Python even mean? The OP is trying to use the `math` module included with Python, and this answer uses the `decimal` module included with Python. So... what are *you* using to get this result?

Comment: @LucasB There's an error of about 8e-15 (after converting the float result to `Decimal` so they can be subtracted), which precludes "exact same" but is almost certainly negligible. `Decimal` has the theoretical advantage (not taken advantage of in this answer) of allowing greater precision. -1 for these reasons.

Comment: @JohnY I took it to mean "using floats and `math`, like in the question".

Comment: @LucasB -- "Vanilla" for me did not work, using Python 2.6.5. As-is threw "OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float". Adding ".0" to all ints to pre-convert to floats resulted in no exceptions, but "nan" result.

Comment: To clarify: vanilla python3.3 using the `math` module and not using `fabs`, but `abs` since `fabs` makes no sense given what the OP tells us.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn In Python 3.3, `math.log(huge_int)` works and gives the correct result (but `float()` does throw an overflow error as you describe). Presumably this was added somewhere between 2.6 and 3.0? I haven't seen any mention of this in the docs.

Comment: To anyone using the term "vanilla Python": If you have to import exactly one **standard library** module in either case, how is one more vanilla than the other???

Comment: @JohnY Maybe they mean they are using CPython and not a different implementation? Then I don't get why use "vanilla" which takes 7 more keystrokes.

Comment: @delnan What is `math(huge_int)`? `math` is a module, that should raise a `TypeError`...

Comment: @JohnY: using builtin types (`long` in this instance) rather than objects of a class defined in a module is definitely more vanilla imo.

Answer (score 3):

[Sympy](http://sympy.org) might be interesting for you. You can do symbolic simplifications and adjust the precision you want to use (using `mpmath`):

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing() # enable pretty printing in IPython

# Build the expression:
X,p,g = sy.symbols('X,p,g')
expr = (sy.log(X) - sy.log(sy.Abs(p))/sy.log(g))
# expr = expr.simplify()  # doesn't have any benefit in this case

# The values:
vX = 53710695204323513509337733909021562547350740845028323195225592059762435955297110591848019878050853425581981564064692996024279718640577281681757923541806197728862534268310235863990001242041406600195234734872865710114622767319497082014412908147635982838670976889326329911714511434374891326542317244606912177994106645736126820796903212224
vp = 79293686916250308867562846577205340336400039290615139607865873515636529820700152685808430350565795397930362488139681935988728405965018046160143856932183271822052154707966219579166490625165957544852172686883789422725879425460374250873493847078682057057098206096021890926255094441718327491846721928463078710174998090939469826268390010887
vg = 73114111352295288774462814798129374078459933691513097211327217058892903294045760490674069858786617415857709128629468431860886481058309114786300536376329001946020422132220459480052973446624920516819751293995944131953830388015948998083956038870701901293308432733590605162069671909743966331031815478333541613484527212362582446507824584241

# substitute values into variables:
expr2 = expr.subs({X:vX, p:vp,g:vg})

# evaluate to 150 digits with internal precision up to 1000 digits:
print(expr2.evalf(n=150, maxn=1000))
```

gives as a result:

```
    769.744342885511619935129482917192487900343653888850271462255718268257261969359878869753342583593581927254506121925469662801405523964742213571689617098
```

**Update:** As noted by  casevh and David, when using sympy, attention is to be paid to not losing accuracy by using normal floating point numbers as inputs. To clarify, let's calculate `10**log10(10+1e-30)`, which obviously results in 10+1e-30:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np

xf = 1e-30

# numpy with floats:
np_x1 = np.log10(10+ xf)
np_yf = 10**np_x1

# sympy with no extra benefit
sy1_x1 = sy.log(10 + xf) / sy.log(10)
sy1_ye = 10**sy1_x1
sy1_yf = sy1_ye.evalf(n=33)

# sympy, done right:
x = sy.symbols('x')
sy2_x1 = sy.log(10 + x) / sy.log(10)
sy2_ye = 10**sy2_x1
sy2_yf = sy2_ye.evalf(n=33, subs={x:xf})

print("correct answer: 10.0000000000000000000000000000010")
print("        numpy:  {:.31f}".format(np_yf))
print("  naive sympy:  " + repr(sy1_yf))
print("correct sympy:  " + repr(sy2_yf))
```

gives as result:

```
correct answer: 10.0000000000000000000000000000010
        numpy:  10.0000000000000000000000000000000
  naive sympy:  10.0000000000000017763568394002504
correct sympy:  10.0000000000000000000000000000010
```

Comment: Setting precision to 1000 doesn't really give you 1000 digits of precision. Really, anything past 16 is meaningless. Reference my answer below which cites the sympy documentation.

Comment: This value is actually correct. The input values to evalf() are all integers so there is no precision loss due to conversion to a 64-bit float.

Answer (score 0):

The "machine epsilon" for the numpy float64 dtype is about 2.2e-16. This means that you should only expect the first 16 significant digits in your result to be accurate unless you are doing something extremely tricky (like rolling your own custom data type).

Dietrich suggested using sympy and setting a high internal precision, but the [sympy documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/evalf.html) confirms that this does not escape the machine epsilon issue.

> some Python floats are only accurate to about 15 digits as inputs, while others (those that have a denominator that is a power of 2, like .125 = 1/4) are exact.

In other words, be extremely wary of the results you get working with numbers as large as yours, because only the first 16 significant digits will be meaningful as long as you are using 64 bit floats to do your math.

Comment: Dietrich's answer is precisely correct to the specified precision. The sentence you quoted only applies when trying to perform high-precision calculations on values that have already been converted to Python floats. Since the inputs to evalf() are integers, there is no loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

In elliptic curve cryptography there are no fractional values, so there is never any precision to be lost, all values resolve to whole number integers.  If a value comes out as a floating point number then the calculation is either being done improperly or in trying to solve it in reverse an improper input is being used.

Also, in the ECC calculation we have more than one coefficients, and so there is no known programmatic way to solve for X or Z in an algebraic equation format, so far as we know it must be found through brute force if the original secret keys are not known.

Also, when attempting to solve these equations, which I see no reason not to try, regardless of how possible it is said to be, you must be careful in dealing with your values like P, G, etc. in that you do not divide a smaller by a larger, as your interpreter or compiler will just return "0" leading you to believe that you have in fact balanced the equation or found a quadratic solution.