# Represent huge numbers without having to use more significant bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am not sure how dumb this question is, but I have an algorithm that outputs huge numbers (more than 1e300). I have tried the arbitrary precision library `mpmat` bu now I want to stick with `numpy`.

as a simple example, how can I store `1e400` without getting `inf` ?

```
a = 1e400
```

I know that I should have more bits storage, but I don't know if there is a way to have less significant numbers while keeping the exponent.

Comment: Can you use logarithmic representations?

Comment: [here is a related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945923/how-to-compute-huge-numbers-with-python). You could use "decimal" numbers which are basically strings with arithmetic operations... Since the numbers are strings you can calculate in principle whatever you want.

Comment: @keksnicoh, this will eat all of the performance and is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Yep thats true. But as a first approach could be enough if you only need to calculate a small set of operations.

Comment: what is the range in values?  you could scale from the minimum or about the mean as an alternative.

Comment: Decimal could do the trick, but since I have convolutions involved the performance would be awful.

Comment: More information is needed.  The suggestions to work with logarithms, or use a better scaling, are good, but without knowing more about *why* you have such large numbers, we can't really answer the question.

Comment: I am curious : which real problem need such a dynamic ?

Comment: It is called holomorphic embedding power flow and it involves the calculation of coefficients that grow exponentially, funny enough each coefficient brings extra precision to a final solution, and I want to check that if it is the magnitude what brigs extra precision or if I need all the numbers